# mimic -i flag in sed when -i not available

Tags: linux, bash, sed, gnu

I am trying to mimic the `-i` flag in `sed` when `-i` throws an error, saying it is not available.
Evidently the server I connected to has an ancient version of `sed` or a version without the `-i` flag.

How would one mimic the edit in place `-i` of `sed` if it were unavailable?

Comment: Use this: `sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/g' orig_file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile orig_file`

Comment: I thought I would have to resort to this. thanks for the confirmation--didn't think about the && mv though. is < necessary before orig_file?

Comment: I am not getting `is < necessary before orig_file?`.

Comment: `sed` can directly read from a file so input redirection is not required.

Comment: sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/g' **<** orig_file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile orig_file         is the less than needed before the original file?

Comment: [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) has < as requisite in this guide

Comment: Failure to support `-i` does is not an indication of ancientness, but merely of non-gnuness.  gnuness != newness

Comment: @William Pursell noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ed:

```
printf ',s/PATTERN/REPLACE/g\nw\nq\n' | ed -s your_file.txt
```